# Stroke circle imageview using canvas on android

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, android-canvas, android-imageview

I'm trying to use a stroke around my circle image, but the stroke is not fitting the circle, it looks like there is a square around the circle and the stroke is passing that limit, see the image below.

```
public static Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
       int size = Math.min(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(size,
            size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    BitmapShader shader;
    shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP,
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Paint paintB = new Paint();
    paintB.setShader(shader);
    paintB.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);


    RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0 ,size,size);
    int radius = size/2;
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, paint);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, paintB);
    return output;
    }
```

xml:

```
  <com.click.CircledNetworkImageView
     android:id="@+id/profilePic"
     android:layout_width="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
     android:scaleType="centerCrop"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
     android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
     android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
     android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true">
 </com.click.CircledNetworkImageView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I look at `BitmapShader` as sort of a magic paintbrush where everything I paint scratches away the canvas to reveal the bitmap underneath.  When I envision that I make fewer mistakes with `BitmapShader`.

So, from looking at your code I'm guessing that you want image inside the rounded rectangle, with a white stroke around the outside.

Since you set your paint style to STROKE, the paintbrush is stroking the shape, so it leaves the bitmap shown where it strokes.

You will want to call `canvas.drawRoundRect()` twice, with the same rect/radius values, but with two different paints.  First time the paint will have the bitmap shader set and a style of FILL.  Second time the paint will have color = White, stroke width = 15, and a style of STROKE.

Comment: Thank you it worked, but it seems a little weird, it's not a circle anymore, it's like octagonal

Comment: That's weird, because you set your radius = size/2, which should be right.  As I see it you have two options:  use drawCircle() instead of drawRoundRect(), or set your stroke width to zero (you should get a hairline white stroke), see if you get your circle, then play around to figure out what the interaction between the stroke width and the corner radius is.  I'm guessing that you have to make some adjustment to the corner radius to compensate for the stroke width.

Comment: I've added an image to the question, I've tried drawCircle() but I still get the same results

Comment: with 0 width I get the circle, there is some square margin around it I guess

Comment: i did it man, it is like that:  `RectF rect = new RectF(30, 30 ,size - 30,size -30);
        float radius = size/2;
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius , paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius , radius, paintB);`